# Eliminating seam between liquid and foam

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency, texture-painting, vertex-paint

Bit of a complicated issue here so let me preface this by saying that I am very new to blender, and complex solutions may go over my head. I followed along with Blender Guru's beginner doughnut series up to near completion, but I wanted to step it up a notch and take the time to get used to nodes and materials.

I decided to try to make the coffee into a cappuccino, and I'm fairly content with the look of the liquid & foam (liquid could use more work if anything). However, my main issue here is finding the proper way to seamlessly transition between the two objects. I've included a picture to better demonstrate what I'm talking about:

[image: Cappuccino]

The coffee liquid and milk foam are currently separated into two individual objects, with texture painting applied to each. I tried to research some potential solutions, but I'm honestly afraid to overwrite my texture painting for each object. I would like to have as much control over that seam as possible, and really blur the line between foam and liquid. It seems that somehow merging the two objects back together and vertex painting between the two materials may be my best bet?

I would greatly appreciate any kind of input or even a nudge in the right direction, I really want to get past this roadblock! Thanks in advance